# Reverse the order of letters encoded in UTF-8

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I have some variable that are encoded in Arabic(UTF-8), but in the reverse order:

```
y <- "سنوت"
```

The right word should be :

```
     تونس    # Tunisia for curious
```

I am trying to reverse this word like this:

```
rawToChar(rev(charToRaw(y)))
[1] "\xaa؈نٳ\xd8"
```

but this doesn't work. Note that this works fine with ASCII encoded characters:

```
y <- "ydutsga"
> rawToChar(rev(charToRaw(y)))
[1] "agstudy"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `strsplit` to separate the characters seems to work:

```
paste(rev(strsplit(y,"")[[1]]),collapse="")
[1] "تونس"
```